# How to find delimiter in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a string :

```
NSString *s = @"a+v+c+d";
```

Where `'+'` is the delimiter.

I want to store each `a,b,c,d` in `array`. How can it be done in objective C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

is the method you are looking for

```
NSArray *yourArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
```

Comment: great answer, short and complete

Answer (score 1):

`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` returns a, v, c, d as elements in an `NSArray`.
Use `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]` if you have more than one delimiter.